# Unit testing an @ObservableObject in Swift Test Driven Development

Tags: swift, mvvm, tdd, observableobject

I'm trying to learn how to use MVVM architecture with TDD to solve some of the problems with not being able to unit test Views in SwiftUI.

I have an Alarm struct which takes a date:

```
import Foundation

struct Alarm {
    var time: Date
}
```

And I have a basic

```
class AlarmPickerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var alarm: Alarm

    init(alarm: Alarm) {
        self.alarm = alarm
    }

}
```

I'm struggling to work out how to write a unit test that fails if the `AlarmPickerViewModel` isn't a subclass of `ObservableObject` and the alarm property isn't `@Published`.

I've looked at [this question on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467247/write-unit-tests-for-observableobject-viewmodels-with-published-results) but it doesn't seem to help me.

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong please?

Comment: "some of the problems with not being able to unit test Views in SwiftUI." That is not true. In SwiftUI you can unit test views - or at least business logic in views, since you can use dependency injection the same way as you would for any other entities. The problem of `UIKit` `UIViews` and `UIViewController`s not being dependency injectable has been resolved by SwiftUI. The only part that you cannot unit test is the actual look of your UI.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a test that won't even compile if `alarm` is not `@Published` by simply creating a subscription to that property, since you will only be able to subscribe to it if it is `@Published`.

The `ObservableObject` conformance adds an `objectWillChange` `Publisher` to your object, so to test that, you simply need to subscribe to that `Publisher`. If `AlarmPickerViewModel` wasn't `ObservableObject`, the test won't even compile.

```
func testAlarmPickerViewModel() {
    let alarmPickerViewModel = AlarmPickerViewModel(alarm: Alarm(time: .distantFuture))

    alarmPickerViewModel.$alarm.sink(receiveValue: { print("ViewModel.alarm updated, new value: \($0)") })

    alarmPickerViewModel.objectWillChange.sink(receiveValue: { print("ViewModel updated: \($0)")})
}
```